# Looking for clarification on return value behavior

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am not entirely sure why

```
function slasher(arr, howMany) {
 var A = arr.splice(0, howMany);

}

slasher([1, 2, 3], 2);
```

returns[1,2]

while...

```
function slasher(arr, howMany) {
 arr.splice(0, howMany);

}

slasher([1, 2, 3], 2);
```

returns [3]

I know the first example is cleaner but I would like to be able to identify why the latter doesn't work. any input is apreciated :-)

Answer (score 4):

Neither of your examples return a value, because none of it has a `return` statement.

If you add the `return` statement both functions still behave the same.

```js
function slasher1(arr, howMany) {
 var A = arr.splice(0, howMany);
}

console.log(slasher1([1,2,3], 2));

function slasher2(arr, howMany) {
 arr.splice(0, howMany);
}

console.log(slasher2([1,2,3], 2));

function slasherWithReturn1(arr, howMany) {
 var A = arr.splice(0, howMany);
 return A;
}

console.log(slasherWithReturn1([1,2,3], 2));

function slasherWithReturn2(arr, howMany) {
 return arr.splice(0, howMany);
}

console.log(slasherWithReturn2([1,2,3], 2));
```

The only difference would be if the first example would return the result of `Array.slice` (the removed values) and the second one would return the modified array (the array without the removed values).

```js
function slasher1(arr, howMany) {
   return arr.splice(0, howMany);
}

console.log(slasher1([1,2,3], 2));

function slasher2(arr, howMany) {
 arr.splice(0, howMany);
 return arr;
}

console.log(slasher2([1,2,3], 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually return anything as you haven't invoked "return." If you do, the two lines of code should give you the same results. Be careful, as the return values look the same but aren't exactly identical in nature.